# How to make a Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to scroll horizontally but when run code some of buttons in first RelativeLayout is out of screen and not scroll to see them. Like the google store that have blocks and each block can scrolled horizontally to see more

my xml :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="626dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />



         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button2"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
             android:text="11:00" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button3"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button4"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button6"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button7"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
             android:text="14:30" />

    </RelativeLayout>
   <RelativeLayout >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button8"
           style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
           android:text="Button" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button9"
           style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:text="Button" />

   </RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`. Try this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- Always set width to wrap_content of the
         first child view with HorizontalScrollView -->
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="626dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />



         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button2"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
             android:text="11:00" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button3"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button4"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button6"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
             android:text="14:30" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button7"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
             android:text="14:30" />

    </RelativeLayout>
   <RelativeLayout >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button8"
           style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
           android:text="Button" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button9"
           style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:text="Button" />

   </RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Zusee, it was not an error but you can have this warning: *should use android:layout_width="wrap_content"*.